# Where do I ask about IDE upgrades and updating project files?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to move from Rad Studio XE8 to Rad Studio 10.1 for my main IDE. I have a preexisting project that I would like to recreate in Rad Studio 10.1 using the project files without using the project file (.groupproj). The thought is that this would be a clean 10.1 start to things while still utilizing what was built in the past.

Given I would like to utilize others' product transition experience and also learn about the product transition in general before trying it myself, I've searched online to find documentation relating to IDE movement from XE8 to 10.1. I haven't found such documentation.

The question I'd like to ask is, is there any documentation online relating to upgrading projects from XE8 to 10.1?

The reason I am asking a question on Meta is because I don't know where I would post the aforementioned question.

SO link to the question I ended up asking thanks to your feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495265/ide-transition-from-rad-studio-xe8-to-rad-studio-10-1/39498776#39498776

Comment: *is there any documentation online* - That's a find request, which is off topic pretty much everywhere on SE. (The few places it isn't wouldn't consider documentation on topic.) You want to ask *how* to do the upgrade, though I don't know if that'd be considered too broad.

Comment: @BSMP Ah yes, I should update the post with the fact that I have searched for 'how-to' documentation etc. I figured that would be more relevant to the question after the (this) question.

Comment: I voted to close your question as too broad. Probably the best course of action for you would be to delete the question before it gets any downvotes. From my POV it is highly unlikely that you will be able to edit it and make it clear and specific enough so it will be on topic for Stack Overflow. For better or for worse this is how this site works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boy, did I stumble into a bit of a mess.

So, executive summary:  yes, your question is on-topic here **provided you exclude the portion asking for documentation on the matter.**  It may be a huge portion of your question in your mind; however, asking for documentation is less desirable than simply asking, "How did you accomplish this transition?"

However, I'm not *quite* sure what you'd want to tag it as.

See...the [rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rad) tag has a bit of a strange use summary that's been there since last November...

> Please don't use this tag, it is ambiguous. For IBM Rational Application Developer related questions please use [ibm-rad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-rad), for other IDEs use tag with the correct name, e.g. [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) , [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) etc.

...and a lot of the questions about Rad Studio [specifically tag delphi...](https://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+rad+studio+xe8&oq=rad+studio+delphi+xe8&ie=UTF-8#q=rad+studio+site:stackoverflow.com)which leads me to believe that the best way to ask about this question would be to tag your question with [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) and specify the versions of Delphi you're trying to migrate between.

The key here is for you to **be descriptive** in your question.  Describe what you're trying to do and what you've attempted (if anything).  Don't ask for any documentation; approach it like you would any sort of question here.

Who knows; this may give us impetus to have a new tag for this IDE after all.

Comment: I like your suggestion question, "How did you accomplish this transition?" I agree that would be better to ask. Regarding using the `delphi` tag, I too find it interesting as I use Rad Studio. The software doesn't force users to distinguish between Delphi XE8 and C++ Builder XE8 and it is awkward that SO does.

Answer (score -1):

Questions about upgrading projects from one IDE version to another belong to Stack Overflow and not to Super User as suggested by @Gothdo. Upgrading projects involves not only programming tools used by developers but also your code and is practical question related to software development as stated in Stack Overflow guidelines:

> but if your question generally covers…
>
> a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software
>   tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable
>   problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But, there are other issues with your particular question and in general with upfront questions asking about upgrading projects.

**They are way too broad.** And as stated in Stack Overflow guidelines:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

First, asking upfront about upgrade is actually asking about potential problems and not about actual problem you have encountered. Most likely answer (or comment) to such question would be *"Try and come back if you have any specific issues"*

But, let's put question part aside for the moment and take a look how such question can be answered. Talking from experience it cannot. Range of issues can go from none (open your project and it runs) to serious show stoppers.

While your particular question was also too broad in sense that you didn't provided any information related to your project like: language used - there are differences in potential issues that are compiler - language related, frameworks you use there is difference in potential issues between FireMonkey or VCL based projects, and also platforms your project supports - Windows, iOS, Android. Each one of those carry different set of potential upgrade issues.

But even if you have provided all basic above information that would not be enough to answer your question. Without knowing your full code nobody can properly answer your question we can only wild guess. Even listing some of more prominent potential issues can end up in you encountering completely different one.

Asking for off site resources (Online documentation and upgrade guides) is also off topic for Stack Overflow.

If you cannot edit the question to make it on topic for Stack Overflow (and for reasons I stated above you most likely cannot) then your question is more suitable for one of Delphi communities [G+ Delphi Developers](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103113685381486591754), [Embarcadero Discussion Forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/) or [Embarcadero Community](http://community.embarcadero.com/) But even there you will receive vague answers and/or people asking for more information because you have provided very little information about your project in the first place.

---

Appropriate question tags for RAD Studio

While you are using RAD Studio, your question should be at least tagged with [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) or [c++builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bbuilder) because those are actual tags that should be used for Embarcadero RAD Studio, depending on the language you use in project.

Comment: You contradict yourself here - you emphatically state that this is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you mention what tags should be used on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makoto: It's not contradictory. The question the poster asked is too broad for SO, and is off-topic for that reason. However, questions about the RAD Studio IDE should be tagged either Delphi or C++Builder, as those are the two languages that are used in the IDE. It's similar to using either C# or VB.net when developing in VS; the question is asking about transitioning projects in one version of the IDE to a different version, and the language used may (or may not) be relevant, but either way someone who develops in one or both of the languages can probably answer it.

Answer (score -2):

I dare to bring attention to the topic at hand:

The poster is facing a transition from an earlier IDE version to a newer. I've just been through the exact same process and I well understand his concerns. I also can answer the question with a few sentences and *actually help* (which I think after all is the idea behind the site and its rules).

Putting the question on hold prevents me (and others) from answering it. I don't see how that improves the quality of the site. In fact I find it quite an appalling behavior to observe. A question on hold is worse than an invalid question that has been answered and accepted.

A lot of text has been generated discussing whether or not the question is valid. Even valid for other sites. How relevant is that?

Much less effort has been put to the original intention - to help the poster. Who has a real-world problem, not one to philosophize about in idle hours.

Measures taken so far have been counter-productive in my humble opinion. I can see that there is no clear community opinion on the validity of the question - so why is it on hold?

Comment: "I can answer the question" I beg to differ. No you can't. [Delphi Berlin Wnat's New](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/What's_New) lists all new features since previous version. It is a huge list and each one of those features (even IDE) ones can have potential issues. You can only list few of issues but that is it. You would also need to mention regression bugs that do happen in every new release. Listing all potential problems would be nearly impossible.

Comment: At the end only possible answer is "Try and see how it goes". I am talking from 20 years of experience in Delphi an moving code between at least 13 different versions, as well as discussing other people's code and upgrading troubles. And that is not Delphi specific issue. Any other dev tools will suffer the same.

Comment: Question already had one answer basically stating "All is good". No, all is not good. There are issues. I had some. I know others had some others. I also know people that didn't have any. This is what makes this question too broad and opinion based. There is no definitive answer to the question asked.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you have considerably more rep points and history on this site than me, your opinion is just that, an individual opinion. I, too, consider Pascal my native coding language and, too, have 25+ years use experience with it. I've been migrating through the versions up to XE8 and very recently upgraded to 10.1 Berlin.

Same as user Makoto, I believe the question has a chance to be improved and to produce an answer that conforms to site requirements. 

Of course, you can use your privileges to enforce your opinion while I can only state mine. So are the rules. :)

Comment: Sure, my opinion is no more valuable than yours. Since you do have a lot of experience then you surely know that what I have written is true. When upgrading Delphi projects you can have no issues at all or you can have serious ones. And it all depends on your code. Which makes answer to the question never ending list of people's experiences and hints. Such questions and answers are off topic on Stack Overflow - not because I say so, but because SO guidelines say so.

Comment: The amount of effort spent on discussing the question's validity versus that spent on creating helpful content on the raised issue is definitely not in favor of the content. I do not question your points, I just feel they would have been better put into a helpful answer or comments. And I cannot share your pessimism about streamlining this issue. You're just assuming the question cannot be made fit or improved by a few questions. Blocking answers indirectly proves that assumption, hence I shall admit defeat. It must be off-topic then.

Comment: If asked on more appropriate place, I would surely add helpful tips and comments. Point is that this is not suitable question for SO. Problem with not suitable questions is that you allow one and next day you have do deal with 100 more unsuitable questions.

Comment: Until 1=0     // cannot be resolved by reiterating

Comment: You both have 20+ years experience and have upgraded from XE8 to 10.1 Berlin. You both have gone through the process and would probably be able to produce a list of steps that you took to successfully get from start to finish regarding an update from XE8 to 10.1 Berlin. Please let me know if you would be willing to produce that list of steps and how I may go about receiving it. I believe each of your experiences is valuable and I also believe in collective experience.

Comment: @Happy to help. Email is in my profile, temporarily.

Comment: I already said "Try and see how it goes". It is impossible to say how will your migration go. If you want my experience: then here it is I cannot use Berlin because of [How to access private methods without helpers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36716363/4267244) How does that help you?

Answer (score -4):

Generally, you can ask questions about IDE on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). However, if you want to ask "is there any documentation online", that would probably be off-topic (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) in Super User Help Center).

Comment: Moving project to new Delphi version is question that does not belong to Super User. It is programming question for sure. However, depending on the question itself it may not be on topic on Stack Overflow either. Most likely it would be closed as too broad.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar does it involves modifying source code?

Comment: @Braiam: Questions about IDEs are appropriate for SO; they fall into the *software tools commonly used by developers* category. SO isn't strictly about code; it's also about programmers tools. This is stated in the [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @KenWhite Why everyone ignores the most important part? "software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is a practical, answerable problem that is *unique to software development***"

Comment: @Braiam: I didn't say that **this specific question** was suitable, but IDE questions in general (*How do I change the syntax highlight colors in Visual Studio?*) are **practical and answerable**, and the average **non-software development** user wouldn't have any idea what Visual Studio is or how to answer the question. Use some common sense, and think about the issue instead of being pedantic about specific words (and then actually **read** the words - **unique to software development** is absolutely applicable to a **programmer's development environment**).

Comment: @KenWhite my critique was more directed towards making "software tools commonly used by developers" the **only criterion**. That's why we have programmers, code reviewer, etc. Neither is "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" or the other three criteria enough. You have to fulfill any of the first three and the fourth, *one of them isn't enough*.

Comment: @Braiam: My critique to you and the answer poster is that *generally* is wrong. *Generally*, IDE questions (including installation, use, modification, and troubleshooting) are suitable at SO; it's rare that they belong on SU, because the average PC user isn't familiar with them and doesn't use them. It is *a software tool commonly used by developers*, and it's *unique to software development* - that's 100% of the tool's designed purpose. I never said that a tool was the **only criterion** at all; I said the blanket statement that *Generally, IDE questions belong on SU* is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: @Braiam There is possibility that source code would have to be changed, too. Depends on the code.